# Sublime Text Syntax Highlight

Tags: sublimetext3

Good morning. In Sublime Text 3 (Windows) I have installed the FountainHead extension. I would like to know where to find the syntax highlight file. Thank you.

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question. I'm not sure why it's being downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is controlled by two files - the language parsing definition file, which ends in either `.tmLanguage` or `.sublime-syntax`, and the color scheme file, which ends in either `.tmTheme` or `.sublime-color-scheme`. `.tmLanguage` and `.tmTheme` files are in XML format, while the `.sublime-*` files are in JSON.

To view specific files in a package, open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>) and hit <kbd>v</kbd>, which should bring up the `View Package File` option. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then type in `FountainHead/` to see all the files in the FountainHead package. The language parsing definition file is in the main directory, and is called `FountainHead.tmLanguage`. The syntax highlighting `.tmTheme` files are located in the `FountainHead/schemes` subdirectory - there are 11 of them.